# Controlling FullCalendar 4 time grid slot height

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a FullCalendar with a TimeGridWeek view.
Each time slot has a height of about 20 pixels.
When I change the slotDuration from 00:30:00 to 00:15:00, the height of each slot stay the same. I would like it to change to about 10 pixels so that the overal height of the calendar stays the same.
How do I do that?

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

[image: 30m grid]

[image: 15m grid]

Comment: If you want to fix the height of the calendar, then see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing

Comment: I tried all of those but with no luck. I'll try to make a runnable demo.

Comment: That would be great. You can fork [this](https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rELXvJ) if it helps you to get started.

Comment: I forked your snippet: https://codepen.io/archemedia/pen/Oedgjv Try changing the slotDuration prop from 30 to 15 minutes. I want the whole day to be visible within the same window.

Comment: `contentHeigth: 'parent',` is a) a typo of the property name (so fullCalendar won't recognise it) and b) using an invalid value. "parent" is valid for the height option, but not for contentHeight. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight .

Comment: Anyway...setting `contentHeight: "auto"` (with no other size-related options) will cause the content area to display without its own scrollbar: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rEPzmy - depending on your screen resolution and monitor size that will then display the whole calendar on one screen. Is that what you need? Or is it more complicated?

Comment: sorry for the typo. What I want to achieve is that with a slot duration of 15 minutes, I get the same content height as with a slot duration of 30 minutes, meaning that the actual height of a 15 minute slot is half the height of a 30 minute slot. I would need a `slotHeight`property which doesn't exist and which I am trying to simulate.

Comment: are you aiming for a specific pixel height overall?

Comment: yes, but the whole time range should be visible within that height

Comment: so in fact I want to change only the grid, not the height

Comment: so what exactly is the specific height value you want, then?

Comment: I mean you could just set something like `.fc-slats td
{
  height: 10px !important;
  font-size: 8px !important;
}` in your CSS - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KjJXMv but it feels a bit dirty

Comment: I updated the question with 2 images showing the same calendar but with different grids and slot heights

Comment: I'll try your solution

Comment: Thx Dyson, that's exactly what I needed! It's a workaround for sure, but it works. It should be a property in FullCalendar IMO. Please answer my question with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for this in fullCalendar (perhaps you could make a feature request to get it integrated). This is a bit of a workaround, and there's no guarantee that some situation might not break it, but in the simplest case you can do something like this in your CSS:

```
.fc-slats td { 
  height: 10px !important; 
  font-size: 8px !important; 
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KjJXMv